# Adding white to a transparent background in GIMP

Tags: inkscape

OK, I cannot for the life of me find an answer to this. Everyone seems to want to create a transparent background. So I'm using Inkscape to create a logo, but to get it sized correctly, I'm opening it in GIMP. The image is showing as white, I've added a white background layer and everything, but when I go to upload it (it's an image for a header on my website) the background is still transparent.

I've even tried just doing a screenshot of the image with the white background showing, but when I upload it to my site it's gray again. Sheesh, right?

Any ideas for why this refuses to show up white? Also, if you know how to just size it properly in Inkscape, maybe that's easier.

Comment: Check the canvas background properties. Make sure its set to white and 100% Opacity.

Comment: Alternatively, create a second layer in your inkscape drawing, put a big white rectangle on it, and set the layer behind the layer that you want to see.  In inkscape the size of the canvas is set under file->Document properties.

Comment: define a background color for the image in css? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 1):

As Amanthety points out in the comments, first thing to do in Inkscape would be to go to File -> Document Properties and set the background color to white (by default it's transparent). To do this, click on the color bar next to "Background color" and set the A (alpha) value to 255. This makes the color opaque instead of transparent. Or, as Charles Green correctly comments, create a white object under your logo. Both solutions will have as a result a white background.

Concerning sizes:

- go to File -> Document Properties and set the size there
- and/or, if
  you export the SVG to PNG (File -> Export PNG image) you can set the
  image size of the PNG in pixels in the export dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Everyone wants to make the background transparent, but I wanted to make it white (!).
I  tried with changing *background colour* in File -> Document Properties, but even removing transparency there, it would not show any background colour on saving (could somebody explain me why?).

Therefore I recommend you to set a white rectangle as background:

1. Select colour white and *F4* to draw the rectangle with the size of your canvas
2. Send it to the back "Lower to bottom" (shortcut *End*)

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx033xneaT4) will help you, it has a similar example.

Enjoy it!